# GSAP Scrolltrigger animation start/end positions don't update when there is a change in another element's height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I have two areas where as the page is scrolled a `h3` animates, using GSAP ScrollTrigger, up over an `h1` element.  Between these two areas is an element, the green box in the pen, that changes height with a button click and GSAP animation.

The problem is that when the green box height is reduced, the start/end positions for the second heading area do not change (as indicated by the start/end markers being further down the page in the footer area).  So the scroll animation does not start when the `h3` element enters the screen from the bottom as expected.

I was going to try with a timer to watch for a change in `window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight` and reset or refresh the animation somehow but that seems very hackish.  There must be a way with GSAP I am missing to handle this situation?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/EOJA/pen/LYexeam), it's not the actual use case but demonstrates the issue.

```
let { Button, Container } = ReactBootstrap

if (typeof window !== undefined) {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
}


const App = () => {
  const box = React.useRef(null),
        titleContainer = React.useRef(null),
        titleScroller1 = React.useRef(null),
        titleScroller2 = React.useRef(null),
        title = React.useRef(null)
  
  let boxFullSize = true
  
  function resizeBox() {
    if (boxFullSize) {
      gsap.to(box.current, {
        height: "500px"
      })
      boxFullSize = false
    } else {
      gsap.to(box.current, {
        height: "1000px"
      })
      boxFullSize = true
    }
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    [titleScroller1, titleScroller2].forEach( x => {
      gsap.to(x.current, {
        y: "-100px",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: x.current,
          start: "top bottom",
          scrub: true,
          markers: true
        }
      })
    })
  })
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Container className="hero" fluid="true">
        <h1>Scroll</h1>
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <Button onClick={resizeBox}>Resize Box</Button>
        <div className="titleContainer" ref={titleContainer}>
          <h1 className="lgHeading">Big Heading 1</h1>
          <div ref={titleScroller1} className="titleScroller">
            <h3 className="title" ref={title}>Small Heading 1</h3>
            <div className="lineAfter"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box" ref={box}>
          Box
        </div>
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <div className="titleContainer" ref={titleContainer}>
          <h1 className="lgHeading">Big Heading 2</h1>
          <div ref={titleScroller2} className="titleScroller">
            <h3 className="title" ref={title}>Small Heading 2</h3>
            <div className="lineAfter"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
      <footer>
        <p>Footer</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Comment: Did you find a slution?

Comment: @Andreas I have posted an answer to this as I was having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not best.... But works...

```
//Init first GSAP
setTimeout(function (){
    //Init second GSAP
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the refresh() function to refresh all of your scroll triggers. [Here are the docs](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.refresh()/).

#### Here's an example:

If, for example, when you click a button an element expands, causing the height to change, what you need to do is refresh the scroll trigger positions when that happens.

E.g. for multiple expanding elements

```
buttons.forEach((button) => {

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      otherElement.classList.toggle("open"); // this causes the height change
      ScrollTrigger.refresh(); // This refreshes the scroll triggers
    });
  });
```

This only works if the height change is instant, if you have a transition, see below.

##### If the elements changing height have a transition

In this case where the elements change height and have a transition property, the height of the page doesn't change instantly, so the scroll triggers will calculate incorrectly.

If so, use an event listener for `transitionend` like so (this example is if you have multiple elements which may change height, like an accordion for example):

```
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");

accordions.forEach((accordion) => {
    accordion.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
      ScrollTrigger.refresh();
    });
  });
```

Now everytime an accordion has finished changing height, all scroll triggers will refresh.

Make sure the element you are listening to is the one that is actually transitioning! E.g. if the .accordion__body is what is changing height, listen to that, not it's parent for the `transitionend`